# Routing using openstreetmap data in ios

Tags: objective-c, iphone, ios7, routes, openstreetmap

How to implement routing using openstreetmap data. Is there any tutorial or example in ios world regarding this. How can i download particular country openstreetmap data and show routing between two selected locations. Is there any API or example to know how to achieve this?

I went through [Navfree](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/navfree-gps-usa-+-street-view/id405922167?mt=8) ios app which shows navigation between two locations using openstreetmap data.

Answer (score 2):

You can try:

- (open source) Route-me: https://github.com/route-me/route-me (check first to see if it's still actively being developed)
- (open source) Alpstein's fork of Route-Me: https://github.com/Alpstein/route-me
- (open source) Mapbox's fork of Route-me: https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-ios-sdk
- (commercial) skobbler's/Telenavs own map & routing engine based on OSM: http://developer.skobbler.com/support#download

Answer (score 0):

There are already multiple examples. Please see [Apple iOS](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Apple_iOS) and [routing](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Routing) as well as [downloading data](http://wiki.openstreetmap.org/wiki/Downloading_data) in the OSM wiki. If you have further problems, please ask a more specific question.

Comment: I went through all these links.I am not getting how to download openstreetmap data, integrate it into my app and show routing between two locations in offline.

Comment: i am not getting the entire procedure of downloading OSM data, integrating it into my app, show maps from OSM data and display routes between two selected locations. Above links list apps using OSM data, but not methods/steps they followed to acheive it.

Comment: That's because there is no single list of steps suitable for every application. Drawing a map requires different parts of the data than calculating a route or searching for data.. Drawing a map requires to render data, routing requires to calculate distances, searching requires a geocoder. Integrating all of these mechanisms into a single application won't be a trivial task and will take a significant amount of time. But for all these tasks there are already web-based services available so you should think about what you really want to achieve before starting your project.