# How to use OSM data in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, ios7, openstreetmap

How can i send request to OpenStreetMap to download OSM data of required region. In what format i should download OSM data? How to render/show downloaded OSM data as maps on iOS.I went through route-me and MapBox libraries, but not getting how to achieve this. I am trying to integrate Offline maps into my current iOS app.

Mainly what are the steps/procedures i should follow to achieve below requirements.

1.I should send request to download OSM data of required regions from my app when user is in WiFi/3G.

2.Render/show downloaded OSM data as maps in offline.

3.Then interact with offline maps.

Comment: Have you tried anything yet?

Comment: You are reasking the question over and over again ([1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25909948/how-navfree-ios-map-works), [2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890740/routing-using-openstreetmap-data-in-ios), [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25887455/how-to-use-route-me-and-load-osm-data-of-particular-countries)). Please try to ask one single specific question.