# Open Street Map for Android and iOS

Tags: android, ios, polygon, openstreetmap

I want to draw some polygons on `maps(OSM)` from the coordinates (please check the image below). I have checked out a few links and stackoverflow but not found the exact what I want. I need `open-source SDK` for both platforms (`Android + iOS`).

- [skobbler](https://developer.skobbler.com/) (paid)

- [mapbox.com](https://docs.mapbox.com/ios/maps/overview/) (paid)

- https://help.openstreetmap.org/questions/8066/ios-android-sdk

- [route-me](https://github.com/route-me/route-me) (very old no maintain)

- [routing-using-openstreetmap-data-in-ios](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25890740/routing-using-openstreetmap-data-in-ios)

- [open-street-maps-api-for-android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8194233/open-street-maps-api-for-android) (here android solution only)

> When I draw OSM polygon in the our native map, it draws a different
>   location on the map view.

Thanks for reading. Any help will be appreciated.:)

[image]

Comment: For Android take a look at [osmdroid](https://github.com/osmdroid/osmdroid).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**My our Investigation**:

> When I draw OSM polygon in our native map, it draws a different location on the map view.

We've selected the Nasr City police station.
`POINT (31.341296458117728 30.068688243368403)` value has been saved in our DB. We used our native `MKMapView` for drawn polygon and it shows a different location compare to [this](https://www.keene.edu/campus/maps/tool/). Same behavior in the android (Google map) too.

We investigate the same place on the google map shows a slightly different position for this value. Please check the image below.
[image]

 URL Generated by [Google maps](https://www.google.com/maps/place/30%C2%B004'07.3%22N+31%C2%B020'28.7%22E/@30.068752,31.3410719,21z/data=!4m5!3m4!1s0x0:0x0!8m2!3d30.0686882!4d31.3412965?hl=cs).

Now, I tried to reverse and used `30.068688243368403`, `31.341296458117728` value on the same map it's working fine.

**Output:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

you can use OSM Nominatim/Polygons